# Get substring between two strings

Tags: c#

I have a string like:

```
string test1 = "The element 'Content' with the value 'blabla1' is invalid - The value 'nana1' is invalid";
string test2 = "The element 'Content' with the value ''blabla2'' is invalid - The value ''nana2'' is invalid";
```

I want to have as result this:

```
1. blabla1 
2. blabla2
```

My code actually is:

```
string result1 = test1.Split('\'', '\'')[3];
string result2 = test2.Split('\'', '\'')[3];
```

But the Value I actually get is:

```
1. blabla1
2. ''
```

I need ony way to solve both with one function. How Can I realize that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not clear what you asking, just giving an occurrence instead you should tell about rules. Like I need string in double apostrophe

Comment: You see what result I actually have... and what result I want to reach... so I think everything should be clear.

Comment: @H.Senkaya, you're free to think that you're clear, but I agree, you should list the rules. According to what you've written, you want to find "blabla1" or "blabla2" in any arbitrary string. When you're asking for help you could perhaps be just a tad more humble and take suggestions more gracefully.

Comment: @Craig: you are right, sorry for that!

Comment: Please note that this site is not a code writing service. If
you [edit] your question to describe what you have tried so
far and where you are stuck, then we can try to help with
specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By skipping *empty items* you can work with *doubled* ampersands

```
// '\'' is a separator, you have no need to put it twice
// but put StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
// so empty lines created by doubled ampersands
// ''abc'' -> ["" , "abc", ""]
// will be removed
string result1 = test1
  .Split(new Char[] { '\'', }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[3];

string result2 = test2
  .Split(new Char[] { '\'', }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[3];
```

Another possibility is to *format out* the text before analyzing, e.g. let's convert multiplied ampersands into single one:

```
String test1 = Regex.Replace(test1, "'{2,}", "'");
// "The element 'Content' with the value 'blabla2' is invalid - The value 'nana2' is invalid"
String test2 = Regex.Replace(test2, "'{2,}", "'");
```

then use `Split`, `Substring` etc.

Answer (score 1):

by using `''` **and** `'` as seperator you should be able to solve this.

```
string test1 = "The element 'Content' with the value 'blabla1' is invalid - The value 'nana1' is invalid";
string test2 = "The element 'Content' with the value ''blabla2'' is invalid - The value ''nana2'' is invalid";

string result1 = test1.Split(new string[] { "''", "'" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[3];
string result2 = test2.Split(new string[] { "''", "'" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[3];
```

Comment: Is it possible to ask for the Content between the first occurence of " the value' " and " ' is invalid "?

Answer (score 1):

Because `blabla2` within double quotes. so use

```
 string result2 = test2.Split('\'', '\"')[3];
```

Comment: it looks more like it is inside double-single quotes, like this `''blabla2''`

Comment: Is it possible to ask for the Content between the first occurence of " the value' " and " ' is invalid "?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of escaping your quotes you should **use double quotes when splitting by single quotes**, likewise if you wish to split by double quotes you should use a single quote to start and end the string. For example

```
string result1 = test1.Split(new string[] {"''", "'"})[3];
string result2 = test2.Split(new string[] {"''", "'"})[3];
```

Your other issue is that both of your criteria are the same, perhaps you meant for the second criteria to be `'\'\''` instead if you don't wish to change to double quotes